# Youtube player stop when rotated

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

My problem arise when I in portrain state start play video and then rotate phone. Video play with few seconds and stops. I set in manifest this config

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

My fragment class

```js
public class YoutubePlayerFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment {
    static YouTubePlayer player;
    static Boolean isPlayPlayer;
    static int playPosition;

    public YoutubePlayerFragment(){ }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        this.setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public static YoutubePlayerFragment newInstance(String url, String key){
        YoutubePlayerFragment fragment = new YoutubePlayerFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString("url", url);
        args.putString("key", key);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.init();

        return fragment;
    }

    private void init(){
        this.initialize(this.getArguments().getString("key"), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                player = youTubePlayer;

                if(!b){
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getArguments().getString("url"));
                }else{
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(getArguments().getString("url"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also I implement onConfigurationChanged and call player.play() but it did not worked

Any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution my problem! The issue was in **FrameLayout**

My initial  code

```html
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/homePageFrameLayoutVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        />
```

And the worked code

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/homePageFrameLayoutVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Before my activity was like this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".activity.FullVideoScreenActivity"/>
```

Then I have added single line of code in it,

```
<activity android:name=".activity.FullVideoScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"/>
```

and it worked. Hope this solution will help others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the Android Monitor log console. It probably says something about youtube video view covered by another view. In details, it gives exact details (view type, id, etc), which view is interrupting youtube video by covering video area.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
youTubePlayerFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
```

in your `onCreate` method after initialization of `YouTubePlayerFragment`.